# JQuery adds a comma when sending a variable to the server

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring

I am using the https://jqueryvalidation.org/ library for form validation. When passing a variable to the controller, a comma is added to the beginning of the string. I do not know why.

Validation code

```
$('#registrationForm').validate({
    rules: {
        username: {
            nowhitespace: true,
            required: true,
            minlength: 6,
            maxlength: 36,
            remote : {
                url: '/checkUsername?username=' + encodeURIComponent($('#username').val()),
                type: "GET",
                data: {
                    username: function() {
                        return $('#username').val();
                    }
                }
            }
        },
```

And this is my controller

```
@GetMapping("/checkUsername")
public boolean checkUsername(@RequestParam("username") String username) {
    System.out.println("User: " + username);
    return !userService.existsByUsername(username);
}
```

In addition to checking what happens, I added a username display and when passing the username to the controller the result is the following

```
User: ,j
User: ,jo
User: ,jon
User: ,jonk
User: ,jonki
```

I did not enter this comma. He added himself at the beginning. Appears out of nowhere.

Comment: I think its bcoz you have `username` two times, 1st in `url` and 2nd time at `data`, thats why it is considered as array

Answer (score 1):

Why have you appended username to url part as well as data field in post data. It is a get request. Do not use post data in that scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove from your validate code

```
      data: {
                username: function() {
                    return $('#username').val();
                }
            }
```

Your final code should be

```
$('#registrationForm').validate({
    rules: {
        username: {
            nowhitespace: true,
            required: true,
            minlength: 6,
            maxlength: 36,
            remote : {
                url: '/checkUsername?username=' + encodeURIComponent($('#username').val()),
                type: "GET"
            }
        },
```

Or you could try :

```
        remote : {
            url: '/checkUsername',
            type: "GET",
            data: {
                username: function() {
                    return $('#username').val();
                }
            }
        }
```